# john said, "David must go tomorrow." would the indirect form be John said that David must have gone the following day?

Tags: reported-speech, parts-of-speech, direct-objects, indirect-objects, direct-speech

john said, "David must go tomorrow."  would the indirect form be John declared that David must have gone the following day ?
or would it be: john said that David would have to go the following day

Comment: Definitely not _must have gone_. Your second version works if you are speaking some time after the event (though you can still use _must_). If you are reporting John's speech on the same day, you can simply say "John said that David must go tomorrow".

Comment: Even many native speakers can get a bit confused about using ***must*** as a past tense. Many people don'rt know that ***must*** is in fact the past tense of ***mote*** anyway (as from a medieval necromancer concluding his Satanic prayers with ***So mote it be***), and most people would much prefer ***He had to do it yesterday*** rather than ***He must do it yesterday***. See [Is "must" ever grammatical as a past tense verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/) as asked on ELU some years ago.

Answer (score 2):

No. *Must have* is **only** used in the epistemic sense of *must* ("I conclude that ... "), not in the deontic sense ("It is required that ... ")

To form the past of *must* for back-shifting, you have to resort to a paraphrase, usually *have to*. So, , either leave the *must* unchanged as Kate says, or use *would have to*, as you suggest.